# Android MAUI Datatrigger binding

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, maui

I have this code in xaml:

```
<Label Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0:F2}', Path=Value}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 20">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="-999,25" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I tried using style triggers and other things, but I didn't succeed

Comment: it seems unlikely that this is causing a null ref.  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: `Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproduce this problem or [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here?